# Return a list of the paths of all the parts.txt files

Tags: python-3.x, list, file, directory

Write a function `list_files_walk` that returns a list of the paths of all the `parts.txt` files, using the os module's walk generator. The function takes no input parameters.

```
def list_filess_walk():
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("CarItems"):
        if 'parts.txt' in dirpath:
            list_files.append(filenames)
            print(list_files)
    return list_files
```

Currently, `list_files` is still empty. The output is supposed to look similar to this:

```
CarItems/Chevrolet/Chevelle/2011/parts.txt
CarItems/Chevrolet/Chevelle/1982/parts.txt
```

How can I produce this output?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's a good idea to show how you're calling this function, which is probably where the issue lies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return list of the paths of all the parts.txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015762/return-list-of-the-paths-of-all-the-parts-txt-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it here--the only adjustments I'd make are:

- Make sure `list_files` is scoped locally to the function to avoid [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).
- Use parameters so that the function can work on any arbitrary path.
- Return a generator with the `yield` keyword which allows for the next file to be fetched lazily.
- `'parts.txt' in dirpath` could be error-prone if the filename happens to be a substring elsewhere in a path. I'd use `endswith` or iterate over the second item in the tuple that `os.walk` which is a list of all the items in the current directory, e.g. `'parts.txt' in dirnames`.
- Along the same line of thought as above, you might want to make sure that your target is a file with [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile).

Here's an example:

```
import os

def find_files_rec(path, fname):
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path):
        if fname in files:
            yield f"{dirpath}/{fname}"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(find_files_rec(".", "parts.txt")))
```