# Return list of the paths of all the parts.txt files

Tags: python-3.x, list, directory, os.walk

Write a function list_files_walk that returns a list of the paths of all the parts.txt files, using the os module's walk generator. The function takes no input parameters.

```
def list_files_walk():
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("CarItems"):
        if 'parts.txt' in dirpath:
        list_files.append(filenames)
        print(list_files)
    return list_files
```

The output (list_files) is supposed to look similar to this:

```
CarItems/Chevrolet/Chevelle/2011/parts.txt
CarItems/Chevrolet/Chevelle/1982/parts.txt
```

How can I produce this output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a list of the paths of all the parts.txt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013905/return-a-list-of-the-paths-of-all-the-parts-txt-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You're searching for `parts.txt` in `dirpath` for some reason when you should be searching it in `filenames`:

```
def list_files_walk():
    results = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("CarItems"):
        for f in filenames:
            if f.endswith('parts.txt'):
                results.append(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
    return results
```

I use `endswith` because it is more accurate than just asking if "parts.txt" is somewhere `in` the filename, but that would also work in most cases:

```
def list_files_walk():
    results = []
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("CarItems"):
        for f in filenames:
            if 'parts.txt' in f:
                results.append(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
    return results
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! Glad to hear that I at least was close!